# Pyqt4-pyqtgraph application recursively opens new instances of itself

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, executable, pyinstaller, pyqtgraph

I forked [BMDanalyse](https://github.com/Frikster/BMDanalyse/tree/develop) for my project and have modified it.

### Setup Instructions in case you need a hand. Actual question follows this.

A 64-bit system is required due to memory requirements. Please ensure you have [64bit Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/).

The following setup instructions work with [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on Windows or Ubuntu, though you'll want to have it running on Windows since my problem is about making an .exe:

The following packages are required. Don't forget to pick the 64bit ones. In the cases where links are provided you will not simply be able to install the packages via Pycharm.

- [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)
- pyqtgraph
- matplotlib
- [PyQt4](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4)
- [pillow](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow)
- [scipy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)
- parmap

After opening the [BMDanalyse project](https://github.com/Frikster/BMDanalyse/tree/develop) you should then be able to run `SPCanalyse.py` to get the app going. It has bugs and is a very early prototype. Download the following [example data](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sfmcupl3ywcypgw/AAAF4EGB4M1FIgjo4TQfK4Fua?dl=0) to make sure it is working as intended.

The following should work if you do it in order. You can of course check your IDE's console for what the app is doing (haven't added progress bars yet)

1. click file, load images, load both images. Click 'Alignment'. After the app does its thing a file called `aligned.raw` should appear in your Downloads folder
2. load the `alignment.raw` image. 'alignment.raw' will appear on the list on the right. Click on alignment.raw. Click ROIs, Add ROIs -> polygon. Draw two polygons as in the following picture:
   [image]
   After you have your ROI's, click Analyse -> ROI Analyis. `ROI.raw` should appear in your downloads folder.
3. Load `ROI.raw.` Click on it. Click temporal filter. After a while `dfoverf0_avg_framesIncl.raw` should appear in your downloads folder
4. Load `dfoverf0_avg_framesIncl.raw.` Click on it. Screen should go black. Remove the ROI's if they are still there. Now click in random places on the black scene. What you are seeing are [seed pixel correlation maps](http://fcp-indi.github.io/docs/user/sca.html)

If all those 4 steps work the app is working as intended on your system.

---

### Actual Question

However, now that it is working I need a standalone .exe of this app that works without any dependencies just to show my supervisor it can be done.

If I use `python SPCanalyse.py` on my main script in the project it runs and my app pops up.

**Update:** My laptop was stolen. However in setting everything up on a clean system I'm struck with different problem. The only major thing I can think of that I did differently is I did not rely on [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) from Continuum analytics for package management.

If I use `pyinstaller SPCanalyse.py` on my main script I get an .exe and if I run that .exe firstly I notice that my icons are missing. Secondly, this happens:

[image]

When I press the alignment button (i.e. go through step 1 in the setup) the app freezes (i.e . not responding) and then repeatedly opens new isntances of itself. I'm assuming this is memory related since this operation does require a significant amount of it. If I look at how much memory the app is taking (looking only at the original "not responding" instance) I see it plateaus at exactly 1,180.8MB each time. Taking all other running processes into account though I'm still only using 28% of my 32GB memory. I have tried setting the priority of the app to high to no effect. I have also tried opening via the command prompt to see if I get any helpful error message. Sadly no.

Do note though that steps 2-3 work as intended! Step 4 results in the same recursive open-itself loop upon clicking the black scene.

I think I found the explanation of what happened here:
https://github.com/rdicosmo/parmap

> Of course, if you happen to have open channels, or files, or other
>   connections that should only be used by the parent process, your
>   program may behave in a very wierd way: as an example, do not open a
>   graphic window before calling a Parmap primitive, and do not use this
>   library if your program is multi-threaded!

I'm thus pretty sure I'm using parmap very very incorrectly. I remain confused why my app works if I run i via my IDE though!

### Old unsolved problem that is now my thief's problem

If I use `pyinstaller SPCanalyse.py` on my main script the following outputs when I try to run the resultant .exe

```
D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse>D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\
dist\SPCanalyse\SPCanalyse.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "BMDanalyse\SPCExplorer\filter_jeff.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\image_registration\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\image_registration\cross_correlation_shifts.py", line 4, i
n <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\image_registration\fft_tools\__init__.py", line 3, in <mod
ule>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\image_registration\fft_tools\correlate2d.py", line 2, in <
module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\image_registration\fft_tools\convolve_nd.py", line 329, in
 <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\pytest.py", line 21, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\_pytest\config.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\_pytest\_code\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\cornelis\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-6xhsyv\pyinstaller\PyInst
aller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
  File "site-packages\_pytest\_code\code.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "site-packages\py\_apipkg.py", line 125, in __makeattr
  File "site-packages\py\_apipkg.py", line 48, in importobj
ImportError: No module named _builtin
SPCanalyse returned -1
```

At first I thought my problem is related to [No module named builtins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495752/no-module-named-builtins) and so I updated my setup.py to include all possible packages I could find that my project is remotely dependent on:

```
install_requires = [
    'pyinstaller'
    'future'
    'astropy',
    'image_registration',
    'scipy',
    'FITS_tools',
    'pywcs',
    'pyfits',
    'pytest',
    'parmap',
    'setuptools',
    'pyqtgraph',        
    'matplotlib',
    'numpy',
    'PIL',
    'SPCExplorer',
    ],
```

I also tried `python setup.py build` and I get:

```
D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse>python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\customItems.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\matplotlib_fix.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\ordereddict.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\ROI.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\SidePanel.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\SPCanalyse.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\version.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\ViewBoxCustom.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
copying BMDanalyse\__init__.py -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\arrow-down-2.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\arrow-left.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\arrow-right.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\arrow-up-2.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\filesave.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\file_add.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\file_copy.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\file_delete2.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\green-add3.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\logo.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\opened-folder.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\polygonIcon.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\README.txt -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\rectangularIcon.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\icons\red_delete.png -> build\lib\BMDanalyse\icons
copying BMDanalyse\changeLog.txt -> build\lib\BMDanalyse
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane\vxray_XY_1.png -> build\l
ib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane\vxray_XY_11.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane\vxray_XY_21.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane\vxray_XY_31.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane\vxray_XY_6.png -> build\l
ib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\XYplane
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane\vxray_YZ_1.png -> build\l
ib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane\vxray_YZ_11.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane\vxray_YZ_21.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane\vxray_YZ_31.png -> build\
lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane\vxray_YZ_6.png -> build\l
ib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\Implant\YZplane
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane\noimplant_XY_1.png ->
build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane\noimplant_XY_11.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane\noimplant_XY_21.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane\noimplant_XY_31.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane\noimplant_XY_6.png ->
build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\XYplane
creating build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane\noimplant_YZ_1.png ->
build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane\noimplant_YZ_11.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane\noimplant_YZ_21.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane\noimplant_YZ_31.png ->
 build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
copying BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane\noimplant_YZ_6.png ->
build\lib\BMDanalyse\sampleMedicalImages\No implant\YZplane
```

When I go to where all this is "built" I see that a [folder with scripts absolutely essential](https://github.com/Frikster/BMDanalyse/tree/develop/BMDanalyse/SPCExplorer) to my program is missing. Perhaps this hints at what is causing my error? See image of what running `build` accomplishes (i.e no SPCExplorer folder):

[image]

I don't know if this or `setup.py` necessarily has anything to do with why running the .exe gives me the error though

Comment: Try adding SPCExplorer to the install requires list?

Comment: Given you have a bounty on this, please let us know if the suggestion by @busfault has worked or not. I would suggest that he has correctly identified the issue (`SPCExplorer` is a module you have made and you need to include it in the list). If this doesn't solve the problem, please let us know in a comment here!

Comment: I am working on it. I've just had a hiccup since my laptop got stolen.

Comment: Hi there . Firstly: Adding that to setup.py made no difference. However, please look at the question. It seems there's a silver lining to my laptop being stolen. I do apologize for the hiccup and can only hope my thief gets whats coming to him. I have tried my best to get something up before the bounty ended but I see I sadly couldn't.

Comment: Seems my issue might well be in the parmap package. Please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem did indeed turn out to be due to multiprocessing. However, if you google 'multiprocessing pyinstaller' you can find [this](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-Multiprocessing)

So as it turns out

Just add `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` after `if __name__=='__main__':`
in your main file (`SPCanalyse.py` in my case) and add `import multiprocessing` at the beginning of the file.

My program now runs as a standalone .exe and meets all four listed requirements